# Control height of flex element within flex-grid without affecting surrounding elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using a flex grid to lay out information. I want to highlight one of the cells within the grid so that it stands out to users by adjusting the height of the respective cell. However, my attempts have not gotten far as adjusting the properties of once cell will thereby affect the surrounding cells.

In my fiddle below, I have a class `.highlighted` within `.flexbox-2` that I would like to change. Basically, the `row 1` of the second column would have a taller height than the first and third column, but all the borders will still be aligned. I was thinking to apply `position: absolute` and change its CSS there, but this does not prove fruitful. I'm wondering if there are other routes I can take.

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yb73cn9/28/)

Code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: helvetica, serif;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.flexbox-1 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: solid 3px red;
}

.flexbox-2 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: solid 3px green;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.highlighted {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.flexbox-3 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: solid 3px blue;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex flexbox-1">
    <div class="flex-row">row 1</div>
    <div class="flex-row">row 2</div>
    <div class="flex-row">row 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flexbox-2">
    <div class="flex-row highlighted">row 1</div>
    <div class="flex-row">row 2</div>
    <div class="flex-row">row 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flexbox-3">
    <div class="flex-row">row 1</div>
    <div class="flex-row">row 2</div>
    <div class="flex-row">row 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the highlighted div to take full height ? and hide its sibling divs ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that first row to stick out above the other two columns, you could use a negative `margin-top`:

```
.highlighted {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yb73cn9/29/)